# How to test programatically that the third softbutton is present or not?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I want to know programatically if the third softbutton is present or not on a device. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to detect the presence of a third softbutton UI. Its an application decision whether to use a third softbutton or not.

Answer (score 0):

[check this link](http://j2mesamples.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-use-alphabets-in-canvas.html) this is one example for checking all keys. 
& [Check this also for detecting soft_keys](http://leahayes.wordpress.com/2009/11/18/generic-soft-key-detection-in-j2me/) so you can get idea how to find third softbutton present or not.
Thanks